# Line Segment Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, parametrization

Let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$. The line segment with end points $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is:

\begin{equation}
[\alpha,\beta]:=\{(1-t)\alpha+t\beta : 0\leq t\leq 1\}
\end{equation}

How do we explain this? My book just says it is obvious. I kind of get that it might work, but how does someone goes about finding this expression? Clearly we have that at $t = 0$ we get $\alpha$ and at $t = 1$ we get $\beta$. However for $0\leq t \leq 1$ all I see is some kind of weighted sum, but I can't visualize a segment between $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Any suggestion? I'd like to find a way to understand this cause I don't want to just memorize the formula, I want to be able to work it out.

Thank you

Comment: a) It's a definition. b) If you look at the line parametrised by $t \mapsto \alpha + t\cdot (\beta - \alpha)$, you may see that the segment from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ matches the part where the parameter $t$ belongs to the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yeah it's a definition, but there is a reason for which they defined it this way and I still cannot grasp this reason somehow.

Comment: The reason is part b). You take the straight line through $\alpha$ and $\beta$, parametrise it, and cut off the parts not between the two points.

Comment: Okay now I see it!  So basically $\beta - \alpha$ is the vector from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ right?

Comment: Yes. And one can write $\alpha + t(\beta-\alpha)$ as $(1-t)\alpha + t\beta$. Sometimes the first form is more convenient, sometimes the second.

Comment: Thank you a lot, finally I understand it, makes sense now! If you wanna write it down as an answer I'll mark your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We take the straight line passing through $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and parametrise it by

$$\gamma \colon t\mapsto \alpha + t\cdot (\beta - \alpha),\qquad t\in \mathbb{R},$$

choosing $\alpha$ as the base point of the parametrisation and taking the difference between the two points as the direction.

Then, since $\gamma(0) = \alpha$ and $\gamma(1) = \beta$, the line segment between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is parametrised by the restriction of $\gamma$ to $[0,1]$. We can rearrange the formula for $\gamma(t)$ to get the given form $(1-t)\alpha + t\beta$.